# Take HTML ID from a website to fill information and press buttons in c# or vb.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, vb.net

I want to code a program that will automatically press some buttons in a website and fill information in the text areas by taking the id of the html.

I would like to know any ways that i can accomplish that using `vb.net` or `c#` (if you know anything that will be easier please let me know). I basically want the program to have a built in Web Browsers and see what it is doing, if that is not possible or there is a way to do it many times faster with a console i would be glad to hear.

After searching in countless forums i found that i could do such a thing with `phantom.js` but to be honest i would prefer to do that with something i'm more familiar with.

I am not asking you to do that for me, just a simple link to where i can find the information is fine.

**Edit

I used AHK & vb.net to do this

Comment: I think Selenium would be useful. Please refer this link : http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows forms you can embed a webbrowser control and programmatically manipulate the DOM content of the HTML document. You also have further control to manipulate the DOM by importing Microsoft.mshtml which extends the basic functionality of the html elements offered by the .Net framework.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigated += WebBrowser1_Navigated;
    }

    private void WebBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.InvokeScript("alert('hello')");
        var forms =doc.GetElementsByTagName("form");

    }

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `Navigated` event. It is only raised when the web browser _**has begun**_ loading the website, thus it may not have loaded all the elements you are going to modify. Use [**`DocumentCompleted`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) instead because it is raised when the website is _**fully loaded**_ (note: can be raised multiple times due to `iframes` and similar elements).